# Unsupported operand type for pow(): 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner trying to find the area of a circle. The calculation of distance(radius) is correct. I am trying to use its value in the area function and then later call it but it is showing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "return_fun.py", line 23, in <module>  
       print area_circle(dist)  
  File "return_fun.py", line 16, in area_circle  
      a= (math.pi)*rad**2  
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'function' and 'int'
```

My code is -

```
import math  
def area_circle(rad):     


        a= (math.pi)*rad**2  
        return a

def dist(x1,y1,x2,y2):  

        rad = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)  
        return rad 


print dist(1,2,4,6)  
print area_circle(dist)
```

Could I please get some help? Also, I'll be grateful if someone can explain how to avoid this error type in general.

Comment: `dist` is a function... you are asking python to compute `dist**2` in the last line of your code... you probably want `d = dist(1,2,4,6); area_circle(d)`

Comment: But if I write print area_circle(rad), it says rad is not defined?

Comment: yes, `rad` is not defined outside of `area_circle`. again, try: `d = dist(1,2,4,6); area_circle(d)`...

Comment: It works now. Thank you :)

Comment: But may I ask one doubt - area_circle and dist are separate functions. So if rad from one function can be used in other function, why can't it be printed separately?